# Generating Random instances of subclasses using a Abstract Superclass

Tags: java, graphics, random, abstract-class

So I have been busting my head over this program assignment and I have no idea how do finish it. I have already completed 80% of it but the last part I don't know even the general idea. The question is

"Then write a method `randomVehicle` that randomly generates `Vehicle` references, with an equal probability for constructing cars and trucks, with random positions. Call it 10 times and draw all of them."

I have a main method, an Abstract Superclass `Vehicle` and two subclasses of Car and Truck. I know how to do probability using loops but I have no idea how to take that probability answer (1 will be truck and 2 will be car) and use it to reference the predefine shapes of the car and and truck.

In other words, how would I create the program that after I hit compile and run, will make these randomly decided car and truck and display it.

Sorry if the question is confusing but I am just learning about abstract classes.

Here is the code thus far:

Main Method

```
import java.awt.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class drawTest extends Canvas{
public drawTest(){
    setSize(800, 600);
    setBackground(Color.white);
}
public static void main(String[] argS){
    drawTest canvas = new drawTest();  
    Frame aFrame = new Frame();
    aFrame.setSize(800, 600);
    aFrame.add(canvas);   
    aFrame.setVisible(true);
}
public void paint(Graphics canvas){
    Vehicle car = new CarTest();
    car.paint(canvas);
    paint(canvas);

}
}
```

`CarTest` Class

```
import java.awt.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CarTest extends Vehicle{

public void paint(Graphics canvas){
    canvas.drawOval(10+super.x, 30+super.y, 15, 15);    // Front Wheel
    canvas.drawOval(45+super.x, 30+super.y, 15, 15);    // Back Wheel
    canvas.drawRect(5+super.x, 10+super.y, 60, 20);     // Bottom of Car
    canvas.drawRect(15+super.x, 5+super.y, 40, 5);      // Bottom of Car
}
}
```

`TructTest` Class

```
import java.awt.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TruckTest extends Vehicle{

public void paint(Graphics canvas){
    canvas.drawRect(30+super.x, 5+super.y, 100, 30);    // Cargo Section
    canvas.drawOval(30+super.x, 35+super.y, 15, 15);    // Wheel Under Cargo
    canvas.drawOval(45+super.x, 35+super.y, 15, 15);    // Wheel Under Cargo
    canvas.drawOval(100+super.x, 35+super.y, 15, 15);   // Wheel Under Cargo
    canvas.drawOval(115+super.x, 35+super.y, 15, 15);   // Wheel Under Cargo
    canvas.drawRect(5+super.x, 15+super.y, 20, 20);     // Driver Section
    canvas.drawOval(5+super.x, 35+super.y, 15, 15);     // Wheel Under Driver
}
}
```

Abstract `Vehicle` Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class Vehicle extends JApplet{

public Vehicle(){
        // Generates Random position
    x = (int)(Math.random()*700);
    y = (int)(Math.random()*550);
}
public abstract void paint(Graphics canvas);

public void randomVehicle(){
    int carTruckChoice = (int)(1+Math.random()*2);
        if (carTruckChoice == 1){
            // don't know if this is the right implementation 
        }
        else if (carTruckChoice == 2){
            // don't know if this is the right implementation 

        }
}
public int x;
public int y;
}
```

Comment: Which part do you have problems with? Creating random numbers? Or creating instances of class a or class b depending on a condition?

Comment: I know how to create the random numbers, I have created the look as to how the car and the truck should look using basic shapes, I know how to create the car or truck when defining them directly to the subclass but what I don't know how to do is to create a method that will create 10 random instances of either the car or truck which are both concrete subclasses and have a abstract subclass.

Comment: Updated with code. hopefully the problem will make more sense

Comment: Your implementation is completely correct. All you need to do is create a new `CarTest()` or `TruckTest()` in each `if`, and you're all set.

Comment: Well I am happy I am on the right track. Makes me feel like my time hasnt been wasted. haha. I just dont know how to "paint" the new type of vehicle in the method.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode to get you started:

```
randomVehicle = 
    randomPosition = randomPosition()
    randomNumber = randomOneOrTwo()

    if (randomNumber is 1)
        vehicle = new Car()
    else
        vehicle = new Truck()

    vehicle.setPosition(randomPosition)
    return vehicle

for 1..10
   randomVehicle().draw()
```

You'd have an abstract class Vehicle, and two concrete subclasses Car and Truck.

Comment: Thilo, you've solved my similar problem. I wanna kiss you right now , but I don't wanna come out as a gay guy

Answer (score 2):

Generally, StackOverflow does not accept homework questions, but I'll make an exception since this is basically an idiom, and since I take it on good faith that you've already tried this.

Here is a method that generates one random vehicle:

```
public static Vehicle randomVehicle(){
   return (Math.random() < .5) ? new CarTest() : new TruckTest();
}
```

**Explanation:**

`Math.random()` generates a number between 0 and 1.

The expression in parentheses tests if it is less than one-half; i.e. it randomly chooses between `true` and `false`.

The question mark is the [Java ternary operator](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018). If the expression in parentheses returns `true`, `vehicle` is initialized to the first operand, i.e. a new instance of `Car()`, and vice versa for false.

Comment: Haha, this is so much more elegant than mine. Bravo

Comment: Thank you. New to this and didn;t know about the homework rule. Won't happen again thankfully. The steps you mentioned I already know how to do thankfully. I have the new object defined to either car or test but I dont know how to draw it/display it.

vehicle.paint(canvas);

Is the default on both car and truck to display the image

Comment: Sorry, it's just that we dislike "please do this assignment" posts. You're fine - you've clearly attempted it, and you've now posted a specific question with code.

Comment: Did you put `vehicle.paint(canvas);` in the `paint()` method in the `drawTest` class?

Comment: Yes, that was the way I learned it. Didn't know of any other way. Is my problem the fact that I am using paint() in the subclasses?

Comment: No, Java knows how to handle that. Your code seems to work. I ran your classes as-is, except that I used `Vehicle vehicle = (Math.random() < .5) ? new CarTest() : new TruckTest(); vehicle.paint(canvas); paint(canvas);` in `drawTest.paint()`. It creates new `Car`s and `Truck`s exactly as it is supposed to.

Comment: No you are absolutely right that it does work when posted in Main.paint() (and thank you for the help thus far) but the issue is creating a method for it that I can call specifically. when I create the method I get the error where the canvas is.

Comment: Nevermind. Totally just figured it out. My brain is fried from this and the other assignments. THANK YOU SO MUCH! I can actually get some sleep now!

Comment: I put the method in my answer in your `Vehicle` class. Your method would have to be changed so that it returns a `Vehicle`, and is `static`. (Make sure you understand why these are necessary.) The code in `paint` now becomes even simpler: `Vehicle vehicle = Vehicle.randomVehicle(); vehicle.paint(canvas); paint(canvas);`. This works.

Comment: I played around with what you just mentioned and got it working. Going to try and minimize the amount of code on the main but it is working as I was hoping! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
public void randomVehicle() {
  Random random = new Random();
  Vehicle vehicle;
  for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
     int randomChoice = random.nextInt(2);
     if(randomChoice == 1){
        vehicle = new Car();
     } else {
       vehicle = new Truck();
     }
//draw vehicle here .. vehicle.draw();
   }
}
```

Comment: Well I did try something similar to this but now I just dont know how to actually draw what was randomly generated since ultimately the code is "vehicle.paint(canvas);" and it is saying that canvas is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate random instances of A subclass then you need 2 things .

1) a data structure holding all "n" instance classes

2) a random distribution of equal probability of landing on any number from 0 to n-1.

The data structure  can be implemented using any linear data structure in java ( a list , array , or enum) which holds classes.  Then, by iterating through 100 random number generations, you can use reflection to generate instances of your class by directly accessing the class from your array (or enum, or list, etc) based on the index.

The advantage of this solution is that, as you add new car types, you need only to add the class name to the array structure... With no other changes to the underlying implementation.